# I want to use only the border at the bottom of my flutter toggle buttons

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, togglebutton

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F32T.jpg)

I hope it helped you understand

Comment: share your code then we may help you.

Comment: Instead of using ToggleButtons, implement it with TabBar and in its property give bottom border to indicator's BoxDecoration property

Comment: Avoid pasting code-image, provide necessary code-snippet that will reproduce the issue

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

For `TabBar` use the `TabBar` in scaffold appbar like here:

```
DefaultTabController(
      length: 2, // length of page you have
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          bottom: const TabBar(
            indicatorColor: Colors.red, // here is red underline
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            tabs: [
              Text('Liste',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              Text('Harite', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: const TabBarView( // have to declare pages when tabbar is pressed to switch
          children: [Screen1(), Screen2()],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

and for your toggle use `Container` as child of togglebutton

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    width: double.infinity,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.grey,
            width: 0.1,
        ),
    ),
    child: // inside of container,
),
```

if you had error for width wrap your `ToggleButtons` with container that has width of double.infinity
[image]

- [example of tabbbar](https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-add-a-tabbar-to-the-appbar-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a toggle widget, according to the design the best widget to use is **TabBar**, which by default applies a border only at the bottom, you can also change the color of it:

```
indicatorColor: Colors.red,
```

Here is some resources about TabBar widget:

[Tab Bar by Mitch Koko](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSheN4Lkhpc)

[Flutter Widget of the Week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POtoEH-5l40)

[Official Flutter Documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs)